# ActivityThread crashes

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-workmanager

Have been getting some `ActivityThread` crashes of which I cannot make much sense. Some of them point to third party libraries which do periodic work like Workmanager, Firebase etc. Root cause of most of these are `DeadSystemException` which says `The core Android system has died and is going through a runtime restart.` but is this so common?

Stacktrace 1:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3689)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3683)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Stacktrace 2:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$100(ActivityThread.java:296)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2165)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:260)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8245)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4500)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$100(ActivityThread.java:296)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2165)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:260)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8245)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

Stacktrace 3:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:4909)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:242)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2079)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7620)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Stacktrace 4:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to unbind to service com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService@89f0968 with Intent { cmp=com.ultrahuman.android/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService }: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:4712)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:301)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2187)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Stacktrace 5:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3205)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1568)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6124)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:780)
    Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
       at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService.onCreate(MediaNotificationService.java:4)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3195)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1568)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6124)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:780)
```

Stacktrace 6:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to unbind to service com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService@762356d with Intent { act=com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START pkg=com.ultrahuman.android }: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3684)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1711)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6953)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:590)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3678)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1711)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6953)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:590)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is spread across various Android versions (9 / 10 / 11). There are no repeat crashes for users as such. How do we mitigate this? Thanks!